# record the topic of a special node between topics with same name

Tags: ros, rosbag, topic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not find the answer of this question anywhere. I rosrun openni_camera and openni_tracker simultaneously. I would like to use rosbag record /tf but only for openni_tracker topic but the problem is that openni_camera is also publishing another topic with the same name /tf.
How can I tell rosbag to record only /tf topics published from my desired node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36907/record-the-topic-of-a-special-node-between-topics-with-same-name/) by [Antares](https://answers.ros.org/users/2375/antares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are two possible solutions to your problem:

1. Launch both the camera and tracker normally, and rosbag record /tf (as you've done), which will have all of the messages published to tf.  You can then filter out unwanted messages using [rosbag filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#filter).

   rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker
   rosbag record tf
   rosbag filter [recorded_bag] [filtered_bag] "m.transforms[0].header.frame_id == '/openni_depth_frame'"
   This will filter only messages with the '/openni_depth_frame' as the frame id (leaving only the skeleton frames, which are children of /openni_depth_frame).
2. [Remap](http://ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments) the tf output of the openni_tracker to a different topic, and then rosbag record that topic, which will contain only the transforms from the tracker node.

   rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker tf:=tracker_tf
   rosbag record tracker_tf
   In this case, the skeleton frames will not be published to /tf, and so will not be visualized in rviz as part of tf, if that is a concern.

---

Originally posted by [pgrice](https://answers.ros.org/users/235/pgrice/) with karma: 196 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1